# How do UQ Holder! and Mahou Sensei Negima! relate?

Tags: negima, uq-holder

I've been reading UQ Holder! since it started coming out. So far (14 chapters into the series) I've understood everything, and (I think) I have not missed any reference or anything similar.

However, just today I realised that MAL lists [UQ Holder!](http://myanimelist.net/manga/57765/UQ_Holder!) as [Mahou Sensei Negima!](http://myanimelist.net/manga/15/Mahou_Sensei_Negima!)'s sequel.
How exactly are the two related, and how much do I miss if I haven't read the latter?
Or is it just meant to be a spiritual sequel, and nothing in the story is related?

Comment: So they span 3 generations in 10 years, as that's how long magic has been around in UQ Holder.

Comment: I think 10 years is how long COMMERCIAL magic is around in UQ Holder's world. Conventional magic (without apps) is shown to be around much longer.

Comment: the mc is negi's grandson, and he is trying to save negi while getting stonger with some of the old crew like fate.

Answer (score 6):

**My post primarily answers the titled question such that the answer works for people that have read and have not read Mahou Sensei Negima (MSN).**

**Part 1 (For people who have read MSN. If you have not read MSN, skip to part 2)**

Remember [Eva](http://negima.wikia.com/wiki/Evangeline_A.K._McDowell) from MSN? She is the same person as Yukihime-sensei. Over the years, Eva figured out a way to change her appearance so she could live life more normally - as an adult.
Basically, everyone from MSN presumably died (since ~100 years have passed) except for Eva since she is an immortal vampire.

Chapter 1:

- Page 1 - Eva gives her introduction
- Page 2 - She shows how the people from MSN are gone now
- Page 5 - Shows her current UQ team
- Page 70 - Eva reveals her true identity to Touta

Chapter 2:

- Page 16 - Eva reverts back to her 10 year old true form. She stays this way until page 38, where she returns back to her older fabricated form.

**Part 2**

Both UQ and MSN are related through Eva, although MSN followed Negi's journey (main character of MSN). UQ's story is being told by Eva, who is reflecting on the past. Eva plays an important character in both series, as her role is to train the main characters, Negi and Touta.

Also note that Touta Konoe is Negi Springfield's grandson (Ch 1 Pg 18). Given that his surname is Konoe, we can also assume he is related to Konoka Konoe from MSN as well.

While UQ Holder is the sequel to MSN, there is nothing critical that you have missed. In other words, you can read and understand UQ Holder perfectly fine without reading its prequel. There are the occasional references to MSN though, but they do not affect the plot in any way.

A good analogy for this would be the difference between Dragon Ball and Dragon Ball Z. You can pick up Dragon Ball Z and fully understand everything without watching Dragon Ball. And in this case, UQ Holder and MSN have a time skip of 3 generations later, so every character except Yukihime is presumed dead now.

Comment: Having been horribly disappointed by Negima's so-called ending, I am thrilled that there is a sequel of sorts. Sad it isn't specifically designed to do the original proper justice. And both that ending and your synopsis makes me wonder: how does Negi even die? He had the same immortality as Eva, yet he gets killed off like any mortal! I hope I find satisfaction in this story...

Comment: @zibadawatimmy maybe you are jumping the gun. I would suggest reading UQ Holder further.... (trying to spoil the minimum possible).

Answer (score 3):

There is another more more more obvious link:

Chapter 1 pg 19: Touta Konoe, the main hero, is the grand-son of Negi Springfield, somehow related to Konoka Konoe (his surname is Konoe).

Answer (score 2):

The good thing about UQ Holder is that even if you didn't read MSN, you will still understand the story.  Yes there are some MSN references which UQ Holder dialogues explain thoroughly especially Negi's "Thunder in Heaven, Great Vigor" was explained in the latter chapters.

As for the other characters, some are not yet dead since not all of them are human like Mana, Eva, and Fate.  There are also characters claiming to know and met Negi such as the Demon with many arms (i forgot the name) Touta fought in the Mahora Martial Arts Tournament, Shion Nagumo a blind swordsman that stated Negi's superhuman magic Magia Erebea fighting the demons of the Lifemaker, and Ruin Ishkur.

Basically, go read UQ Holder and you'll still understand everything but it is an advantage if you have a bit background (most especially on the characterns) in MSN.

Answer (score 0):

First not all of the characters are dead and like said above they relate through Eva(who is Yuki). Personally I would read negima because characters from it reaqure in UQ Holder. Plus you need to know most of the background in the manga to experience a more exciting storyline. Especially when previous characters return in this manga.